# Controllers across multiple files in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to modularize the implementation of an angular js project. I am aiming to implement different controllers in their own js files. But that doesnt seem to work.

The following is my config.js ( where the primary module is also defined )

```
(function() {
var app= angular.module("spa", [

    //oob angular modules


    //3rd party modules
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', configRoutes]);

//function to config the routes

function configRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '../App/Views/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

    .state('supplier', {
        url: '/suppliers',
        templateUrl: '../App/Views/supplier.html',
        controller: 'supplierController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

    .state('event', {
        url: '/events',
        templateUrl: '../App/Views/event.html',
        controller: 'eventController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

    .state('partner', {
        url: '/partners',
        templateUrl: '../App/Views/partner.html',
        controller: 'partnerController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })





    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}

app.controller('dashboardController', dashboardController)

function dashboardController() {
    alert('dashboard-same function');
}
}());`
```

the dashboardController triggers fine. But other controllers, written in seperate files dont trigger.

```
(function () {

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('spa');
app.controller('eventController', eventController);

function eventController() {
    alert('event');
}
});
```

This is the sequence of my references:

```
<!--External Libs-->
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>   

<!--Jquery Plugins-->

<!--Custom Libs-->
<script src="../App/Common/config.js"></script> 

<!--Controllers-->
<script src="../App/Controllers/event.js"></script>
<script src="../App/Controllers/partner.js"></script>
<script src="../App/Controllers/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="../App/Controllers/supplier.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your sure, Is the dashboardController triggers fine?

Comment: yes it does. But eventController, in event.js doesnt trigger at all. It throws the generic `Argument 'eventController' is not a function, got undefined` error

Comment: In your `eventController`,the function wrapping your controller isn't being executed. Change the last line from `});` to `})();`. If this is a typo in your question, please create a jsfiddle where we can try and fix it. Also I don't see routes.js in your html.

Comment: `controllerAs: 'vm'` - these all being the same ('vm') smells funny to me. (I not sure it's the issue though, I don't declare controllers in my routes at all, they go in directives).

Comment: @lclk bang on the spot. Thanks for the pointer. Its a mistake I do so many time s :/

Comment: @lecstor i am not sure what it does, i am following a sample angular js implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you forgot to execute the wrapping function of **eventController.js**. It should be

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('spa');
  app.controller('eventController', eventController);

  function eventController() {
      alert('event');
  }
})();
//^^--------You forgot these
```

If it doesn't work after said fix, please create a fiddle from your local code instead of the fiddle code to prevent any typo errors and I will take a look.

Also I don't see routes.js in your html, or maybe you meant config.html.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what is going wrong on your side, but here is an example of how I do it:

For example I am using the following setup for modularizing my AngularJS app (v1.3.6):

**index.html:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modularize</title>

    <!-- load module -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.constant.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.config.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.run.js"></script>

    <!-- load controllers/services/directives/factories -->
    <script src="app/controllers/MyController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- REST OF THE APP -->
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
var myapp = angular.module('spa', ['ui.router']);
```

**app.constant.js**

```js
myapp.constant(function () {

});
```

**app.config.js**

```js
myapp.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html',
            controller: 'MyController',
        });
});
```

**app.run.js**

```js
myApp.run(function () {

});
```

**MyController.js**

```
myapp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

});
```

Comment: `var app= angular.module(''spa', []);` is in one file only. I am using 1.3.15 version of angular js. Global variables are not allowed. How am I supposed to associate a controller without re-referencing the existing module. As per my knowledge `var app = angular.module('spa');
`.  only acts as a getter and refernces to the existing module

Comment: I am using 1.3.6 and I added an example

Comment: only one file should do `var app = angular.module('spa', []);`. As many files as you like can do `var app = angular.module('spa');`

Comment: yup, sorry, was just backing you up there.. 8)

Comment: @MarkVeenstra as per my understanding, you need to wrap all code in an 'iffy' so that there is no global variable. With multiple files, you would need multiple iffies. You can't acess variables of one iffy in another.